# Craft admin page 403 at home

Tags: admin

I can access Craft admin page at work, but I cannot access the admin page at home.
Is it limited by IP address in the code?
The whole site is hosted at vendor's server with Plesk web host edition.

I am new to Craft. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer. The config is in "Additional nginx directives"

Comment: Thanks for following up to share what worked, xyray! If you have time, I'm sure it'd help future visitors to expand a bit on both the problem and how you solved it. (Detailing exactly what you were seeing trying to access from home, then exactly what you ended up changing in Plesk in your answer, for example.)